# Why this dotless question mark code does not work in standalone class?

Tags: standalone

See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304506/215887.

I wanted to use the following command in the answer:

```
\newcommand{\?}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \sbox0{.}\sbox2{?}%
    \hspace{-.1\wd2}%
    \raisebox{1.1\ht0}[0pt]{%
      \clipbox*{{-.1\wd2} {1.1\ht0} {1.1\width} {1.1\height}}{?}%
    }%
  }%
  \phantom{?}%
}
```

in the following standalone document:

```
\documentclass[preview, varwidth, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\dotlessque}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \sbox0{.}\sbox2{?}%
    \hspace{-.1\wd2}%
    \raisebox{1.1\ht0}[0pt]{%
      \clipbox*{{-.1\wd2} {1.1\ht0} {1.1\width} {1.1\height}}{?}%
    }%
  }%
  \phantom{?}%
}

\begin{document}
\dotlessque
\end{document}
```

The code works in an article document, but it **only renders whitespace** in the above standalone document. **How to make it work in a standalone document?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm your observation, while this one does work:

[image: result]

```
%\documentclass[preview, varwidth, border=1cm]{standalone}
\documentclass[ border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\newcommand{\dotlessque}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \sbox0{.}\sbox2{?}%
    \hspace{-.1\wd2}%
    \raisebox{1.1\ht0}[0pt]{%
      \clipbox*{{-.1\wd2} {1.1\ht0} {1.1\width} {1.1\height}}{?}%
    }%
  }%
  \phantom{?}%
}

\begin{document}
\dotlessque
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh that was easy (: Yes, I've never thought options would be the cause. It seems also the case that preview option is innocent, varwidth is the problem. Though, I now realize my document desperately needs varwidth option.